# Blender "eats" frames as I render animation with video as plane's texture

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing

[image]

[image]

So I want to make a lightsaber.
As I animate glowing plane on top of video ([I used a plane and then added video as texture as advised here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVUeRIY1E-M&t=59s)) everything seemed fine. The plane was aligned with the stick I was holding in my hand.

Then, as I started rendering the whole thing, animated plane started lagging behind the video. It was like Blender skipped and duplicated frames whenever it wanted to. Any suggestions on how to solve it?

One more thing. I duplicated the "video plane" so that lightsaber isn't visible as it passes behind something. Also, I finally managed to align everything, and render was ok. As I came back to the project after rendering, it was missaligned again, but next render looked fine.

Comment: Hello, could you add a few screenshots of your setup ? The description is a bit confusing. Make sure you don't have rogue keyframes in your object's animations

Comment: Ok, added few. This "side view" are mentioned earlier planes I used as masks

Comment: I'm also a bit lost in your explanation ... when you "...managed everything, render was OK." ... you mean single frame render? Also "... but next render looked fine." Like when rendered anim again it was OK? BTW are you sure your video is at 30 fps like blender's fps is set now?

Comment: Is the video a video file or an image sequence? I try to always work with image sequences because it's less likely to have codec issues or framerate issues. Try exporting the video as an image sequence using a video editing software (I'm pretty sure you can do this in Blender, but I'm not familiar at all with Blender's video editing tools) and then use the image sequence as the texture. I believe this sort of problem won't happen then.

Comment: @vklidu I meant animating it basically frame by frame again. After that I rendered it again and it was fine. The video should be in 30 fps. It's recorded with phone, so maybye that's an issue, but in file properties it had 30.01fps. So yes, it's a video. I tried again while waiting for an answer and it seems, that it got messed up after adding these mask planes. Now I added them before animating the blades and it seems to be working fine